# GIMP Script-fu/Python-fu: apply filter or color to all layers?

Tags: python, gimp, script-fu, gimpfu, python-fu

Okay, I'm fairly new to GIMP scripts/plug-ins and stackoverflow so I apologize in advance for any blunders I'm prone to make.

Anyway, I have Windows 8, GIMP 2.8.22, GAP, and animstacks all for the purpose of making high quality gifs. Recently I noticed GAP Frame Scale (plug-in-gap-anim-scale or [ANIM_SCALE](http://www.ibiblio.org/studioforrecording/site01182008/tom.fc8/temp/gimp-gap-2.2.2/gap/gap_main.c)) resizes every frame/layer in a single file, and I'm curious; using GAP's defined parameters or similar code, *is it possible to automate other plug-ins to transform every layer?* For instance, a script or plug-in for unsharp mask or levels that applies to each layer in the file.

If it's been done before or there's a simpler method of achieving my goal (applying filters and colors to every frame of a gif) then please let me know! I barely know how to read code, but to me it appears achievable to combine GAP's .xcf animation function with filter or color scripts.

P.S. You're welcome to answer my question on [gimp-forum](https://www.gimp-forum.net/Thread-GIMP-Script-fu-Python-fu-apply-filter-or-color-to-all-layers), and let me know if this doesn't belong in the python tag!

**UPDATE 29 JUN:** I've copied enough from tutorials to make a working script for my sharpening, brightness, and color settings. You can see the template code at pastebin.com/PrXmS5u3, does anyone know how to have it apply to all layers?

Comment: well i am needing such a script myself. I want to apply an artistic filter across about 400 layers individually, and then extract each layer as an image, and create a frame by frame animation of the same. For 10 or 20 frames, i am able to do this manually.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no...

- In the general case, yes, there are few things(*) that you cannot do to a layer with a script, so it could be a Small Matter Of Programming to iterate the process over the layers.
- For many plugins, it is often quite simple since the plugin API takes the same parameters as the plugin GUI (those for which the GUI is auto-generated from the API)
- But there are plugins that have a different set of parameters
- And there are tools where the API is very different from the GUI, when it exists at all (freehand selection, quick mask..)
- And you have to consider processes that are a mix of the above...
- And all the above assumes that you write a dedicated script for each target processing.
- There may be ways using to write a sufficiently general code that could take a simple plugin (second item above), discover the parameters, ask the user for parameters, and iterate it, but if you want to use two scripts in sequence you will have to manage all the parameters of all the scripts, when in practice parameters of the scripts are often interrelated.

So, all in all, a lot of effort for not that much value (unless I am missing something...).

A completely different way of solving the problem is to transform the image frames into a tile sheet, process the sheet manually with the full power of the GUI, and then split the tile sheet into frames when done (assuming this produces an image of manageable size).

(*) but these exist...

Comment: Well, without a script I would have to use a few shortcut keys 1600 times on an average 80 layer gif to brighten and color the individual frames. Now, with a script I can cut it down to 160 key presses by making all the brightness and color settings a script and simply going down each layer and repeating the last process for eighty layers. Obviously pressing two keys 160 times for one gif is still ridiculous, that could easily amount to 1600 again for ten different gifs and on average I make 150 gifs in two weeks which is 24000 reiterations. It's valuable to me, and my keyboard's well-being.